# How to port Maemo 5 to custom embedded device?

Tags: embedded-linux, maemo

I want to port Maemo 5 to custom embedded device ( ARM9 450 Mhz running Embedded Linux), Is it possible? Where can I find source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code is here:
http://maemo.org/development/sources/

As for porting it to a new platform, you should download the code and see if you can compile it. It targets ARM systems so at least you have a chance.

Answer (score 2):

if your platform doesn't have enough hardware features, it might "be possible but not practical" - N900 has TI OMAP3 chip inside; which in turn has graphical accelerator from Imagination Technologies; which in turn makes a lot of mundane graphical things; so if yours ARM9 450 Mhz doesn't have enough capabilities in hardware, it might spent almost whole CPU power into emulating low-level things. So you can start porting but it might turn impractical after a lot of effort is done.